# Is there any way to get information about how many files are incoming and outgoing files in our Android phone

Tags: android, file, filesystems

I am graduating student of I.T. branch.
I want to gather information about how to detect which files are recently incoming/created/download and which are outgoing/deleted/uploaded in our Android phone.
So, if you guys having any information about this, please tell me.